# Error Loading openemm-2013.sql to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, plesk, centos6

I am using Plesk 11 on a Centos6 server and have created an openemm database but when I try to import the openemm-2013.sql file into it I am receiving the following message:

```
QL query:

GRANT DELETE ,
INSERT ,

UPDATE ,
LOCK TABLES ,
SELECT ,
ALTER ,
INDEX ,
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ,
DROP ,
CREATE ON openemm . * TO 'agnitas'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'openemm';

MySQL said:

#1044 - Access denied for user 'openemm'@'localhost' to database 'openemm'
```

I have created a database user named openemm. What's causing this problem? Is there a password somewhere in openemm-2013.sql that needs to be set for the openemm user? It does appear that the database became populated, and I see the offending script appears at the very end of the openemm-2013.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Is password is correct?

Also check permissions of 'openemm'@'localhost' it's should have GRANT OPTION;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option

Query to check:

```
show grants for 'openemm'@'localhost';
```

To add grant option you should grant privileges "WITH GRANT OPTION" like:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON horde.* TO 'openemm'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If 'openemm'@'localhost' is created from Plesk I suppose that there is no GRANT OPTION on this user and this is ok. 
In this case you can create new user "agnitas" for database "openemm" in Plesk GUI and remove string

```
GRANT ... ON openemm . * TO 'agnitas'@localhost' ... ;
```

from openemm-2013.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using 'openemm' as the username, which is not defined in agn.py.

The default username is 'agnitas' and the password is 'openemm'.

Make sure db usernames and passwords are correct in library agn.py located in:

```
/openemm/openemm-backend/src/main/scripts/lib/agn.py
```

```
line:274    for (eid, keyUrl, keyUsername, keyPassword, defaults) in [
line:275      ('emm', 'jdbc.url', 'jdbc.username', 'jdbc.password', ['localhost', 'agnitas', 'openemm', 'openemm']),
line:276      ('cms', 'cmsdb.url', 'cmsdb.username', 'cmsdb.password', ['localhost', 'agnitas', 'openemm', 'openemm_cms'])
line:277      ]:
```

I hope this helps.

-Yamen-

Comment: Thanks -- I gave up on OpenEMM and installed PHPList.